# Java - defining unknown number of variables in an entity

Tags: java

I need an entity called DynamicEntity for example, in which I must define an UNKNOWN number of variables with theyr setters and getters. The variables must have a name I want to give them, so for this i got:

The main class:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DynamicEntity dynamic = new DynamicEntity();

    dynamic.parseVariable("int");
}
}
```

And the DynamicEntity class:

```
public class DynamicEntity {
public void parseVariable(String text) {

    String[] tokens = text.split("-");
    String variableType = tokens[0];
    String variableName = tokens[1];

    if (variableType.equals("int")) {
        int variableName = 0;
    }
}
}
```

Definetly the variableName will not be accepted due to its defined already.

The thing is that i dont want the variable inside the IF to be called variableName, I want the variable to be called as the whats inside the tokens[1].

And of course creating setters and getters for every new variable added, which i have no clue what to do for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can benefit from the Map structure. Where as the key you put the name of your member and as value the value for it.

A simple example of concept:

```
class Dynamic { 
  private final Map<String,Object> members = new HashMap<>();

  public void setMember(String name, Object value) {
      members.put(name,value);
  }

  public Object getMember(String name) {
     return members.get(name);
  } 

}
```